# How is shear stress exerted onto a fluid?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, stress-strain, viscosity

I am currently studying fluid mechanics and one of the most important concepts we come across is that of shear stress. I understand that it is a force that is acting on the fluid in a direction that is tangential to the surface, as opposed to normal stress that is perpendicular to the surface. I can perfectly understand normal stress because I can imagine the force of atmospheric pressure being exerted on the surface of water in a stationary cup of water. However, I can't really imagine a real-life example of shear stress. Do I exert shear stress on the water in the cup when I push the side of the cup horizontally (i.e. in a direction parallel to the water surface)?

My other more educated guess as to what shear stress is would be that as a fluid flows in a pipe, the different layers of the fluid exert a "drag force" on each other. These forces are tangential to the surface of each "layer" of the fluid. This seems to be more likely to be correct, is it?

In this question, I'm more interested in the intuitive understanding of the concept of shear stress and detailed examples of it, as opposed to a mathematical description, which has already been discussed in other posts on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Shear stress arises whenever we load a material in any way **other** than equitriaxial stress.

(Equitrixial stress, also known as dilatational stress, corresponds to equal normal stresses in all three orthogonal Cartesian axes, and no other stress components; the compressive version is [hydrostatic pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatics#Hydrostatic_pressure). Any other stress states correspond to some degree of [deviatoric stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor), which induces shear.)

Since ideal fluids can't sustain a shear stress—equivalently, their shear modulus* or stiffness is zero—fluids rearrange under shear stresses to eliminate them.

*I review the differences between the shear modulus and bulk modulus, among other elastic moduli, on my own site [here](http://john.maloney.org/Structural/overrating_youngs_modulus.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Water flowing over a stream bed exerts a drag force on the stream bed. This is because of viscosity - friction between adjacent layers of water. Those near the bed flow slower than those higher up. It may be easier to visualize with a stream of honey.

Also think of a sheet of plastic laying on the bottom. Suppose the bottom surface of the sheet was frictionless. Honey would drag it along the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So the friction between layers of fluid is a form of shear stress. Seemingly, all the examples you have given are either friction or drag force. Are there other examples of shear stress within a fluid or between a fluid an an external surface?

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to ask if it is correct to think of the viscosity of a fluid as the "stickiness" between the layers of fluid, so the higher the viscosity, the greater the shear stress required to produce a certain rate of deformation/shear strain?

Comment: If you look at the tensor definition, the xy component is the force two adjacent layers normal to the x axis exert on each other in the y direction. Much like pressure is the force two adjacent x layers exert in the x direction. A friction force would certainly create shear stress, and it is the common example. But perhaps you could imagine a magnetic fluid doing something similar.  Plasmas can support a surprising amount of shear stress. Or you might think of an elastic solid like jello.